# Changing row order in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any way to change the order of rows in a MySQL table?
I want to change the order what will be returned for the most basic query:

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

The query doesn't contain ORDER BY part.

The query is given and I can't change it. I only have access to the database.

Comment: What you have tried? If you simply want to use order by follow this http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp It is not actually a question or not well explained.

Comment: The ***only*** way (really, the only) to ensure an order is to add an `order by`. There is **no** other way to guarantee an order.

Comment: What do you mean by *the query doesn't contain ORDER BY part*? What framework are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of "default order" does not exist in the SQL language, no matter what quick testing may reveal. Sorting rows adds an overhead to the query and it'd be poinless to make queries slower when the app does not require sorting.

So the answer to your question is "no".

Comment: I was thinking more about query, that would once change the physical order of rows in the file with table. But this is the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY [column name]
```

You can choose which way it is ordered by adding ASC or DESC to the end:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY [column name] ASC
```

Comment: Thanks george for answer. I have access just to the database. The query doesn't contain ORDER BY part.

Comment: @Peter: Then you add the `ORDER BY` part. There is no other way.